# TypeScript type error with drizzle-orm and zod validation

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-types, drizzle

I am currently working on a project that involves using drizzle-orm and zod for validation in a TypeScript environment. My issue arises from the interaction between these two libraries, specifically when dealing with the InsertOrderType type provided by drizzle-orm. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
// From drizzle schema
export type InsertOrderType = InferModel<typeof orderSchema, "insert">;
```

The InsertOrderType type works well with drizzle-orm, but I need to manually calculate the "amount" field for security reasons and exclude it from the zod validation schema. Here's my zod validation schema:

```
import * as z from 'zod';

const orderSchema = z.object({
  // ... other fields ...
  // 'amount': How can I exclude this field from here?
});
```

Now, since the "amount" field is missing from the zod validation schema, my InsertOrderType is throwing type errors due to the missing "amount" field.

I've tried setting "amount" as optional in the zod validation schema, but this approach doesn't seem to work as it still complains about missing "amount" in the InsertOrderType.

How can I handle this situation properly? Am I approaching this the wrong way with TypeScript types? Is there a way to exclude the "amount" field from the zod validation schema while still keeping it compatible with drizzle-orm? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, Zod is helping you with user input validation. It makes sure the value is set and satisfies certain criteria. You nonetheless should read, and properly validate, or override with a backend calculation logic, to make sure the value is "correct" before inserting into your DB. This isn't necessary an ORM/Zod issue, but rather how you handle your backend logic.

---

If you want to make a required field optional (if I understood your  question correctly), see below:

Ideally you `Pick` the fields you need, but in the case where you only need to make one field optional, you can do so by merging two schemas. A.merge(B), where keys in B override keys in A

Below solution should likely satisfy your requirements

```js
const orderSchema = z.object({
  // ... other fields ...
  // 'amount': How can I exclude this field from here?
}).merge(z.object({
  amount: z.number().optional()
}));
```

[Zod merge docs](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#extend)

From the docs

> If the two schemas share keys, the properties of B overrides the property of A. The returned schema also inherits the "unknownKeys" policy (strip/strict/passthrough) and the catchall schema of B.

Comment: My drizzle schema expects an "amount" field, but the zod validation does not provide a "amount" property in its returned value or suitable type. Consequently, this inconsistency results in a type error being thrown.

Comment: Since I don't intend to include "amount" in my zod validation, what would be the best practice for handling this situation?

Comment: I see, you could use above approach (merging the schema) to add it for the Drizzle validation, and then create a second type for the return without amount by omitting it `oderSchema.omit({amount: true})` - is this what you need?

Comment: @hantoren is it solving your problem?

Comment: yes thx, that kind of works :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a completely separate answer.. I need 2 more reputation points before I can comment.

Anyway, while Michael's answer is correct I wonder if there is a misunderstanding at play here regarding the stripping of unspecified properties when using parse.

If you specify the amount as optional in the first validation then it will not be stripped and it will then be available in the second.
However, it may be more useful for you to use safeParse in order to get the validation result without the stripping feature.

https://zod.dev/?id=parse

Notice the information about parse cloning the input. It does this so the type inferred by it's result is accurate and matches what you said it was.

I hope this helps someone, Zod is an amazing library and very powerful if understood and used to meet your requirements.